# How to check DNS name availability using Azure Powershell

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell, azure

Is there a way to check DNS name availability using Azure Powershell?  Similar to Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability but for DNS names?

I know there is the REST method [Check Dns Name Availability](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/CheckDnsNameAvailability/CheckDnsNameAvailability), but I was hoping not to have to get an authorization token when I already have an AzureRM context.

Comment: Are you talking about checking if a DNS entry is present in an Azure DNS zone? Or if one just exists in general on the public internet?

Comment: Or are you trying to check if a name has been registered with a domain registrar, regardless of whether any DNS entries have been created for it?

Comment: I would like to use the Azure functionality provided by the REST method I linked to in the question.  But using the Azure Powershell Cmdlets. Mainly so I don't have to go through the step of registering the script as an application and getting an access token.  And then authorizing each time the script is run.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an Azure cmdlet to check if a particular DNS record exists. You can just... query it.

For example:

```
Resolve-DnsName example.cloudapp.azure.com -Type A
```

or

```
Resolve-DnsName stackoverflow.com -Type A
```

If you are wanting to check against a specific nameserver (say it's one that you don't have your NS records configured for yet)

```
Resolve-DnsName stackoverflow.com -Type A -Server 172.16.114.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after? Looks to be a script rather than an inbuilt function https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tip_of_the_day/2017/02/16/cloud-tip-of-the-day-use-powershell-to-check-domain-availability-for-office-365-and-azure/

Comment: Due to different Azure locations having different domain entries I don't think I can use this.